# Wordpress LaTex Equations

Tags: wordpress, latex

Having trouble with latex formulas. For instance, for the following I get "Formula does not parse":

```
(\epsilon, F_\alpha_2, \epsilon) \rightarrow (F, \alpha_1)
```

There are a lot of formulas that break down with no apparant reason. For instance the previous sample works on http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php

I use WP Latex plugin set with the wordpress.com Latex server.

Really frustrating. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `(\epsilon, F_{\alpha_2}, \epsilon) \rightarrow (F, \alpha_1)`. This should work.

LaTeX does complain about the `F_\alpha_2` part. It does not know if you want to have `F_{\alpha 2}` (i.e. `alpha` and `2` on the same lavel) or `F_{\alpha_2}` (`\alpha` and a subscribt`2` within the subscript).

If you do not surround the subscript part with `{` and `}`, LaTeX takes only the next sign as subscript. But since you want two signs in subscript (`\alpha` and `2`), you have to parenthesize it somehow.

Comment: Great! that worked. but it doesn't explain why it wouldn't parse `(\epsilon, F_{\alpha_n}, \epsilon) \rightarrow (F_{\alpha_{n-1}}, \alpha_{n-1})`

Comment: Forgot to to notify :) @phimuemue

Answer (score 0):

I have no answers, but I can confirm your statement that the LaTeX is correct.  I used the [EquationSheet](http://www.equationsheet.com/textoimage.php) site.  Here's what it returned for your input:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had very similar problems when creating my Maths Training platform (for GCSE exams), I changed my setup and used MathML block which solved issues. Hope this helps.